# mysql ORDER BY по where запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

Не знаю возможно ли такое или нет.

Есть sql запрос

```
       SELECT
            TEXT
        FROM search_site_text
        WHERE 
            (TEXT like 'такси%' OR SYNON like 'такси%') 
            or (TEXT like '%такси%' OR SYNON like '%такси%')
        ORDER BY TYPE asc   
        LIMIT 100
```

Нужно чтобы с начало появились результаты начинающиеся с такси%, а после %такси%

пример какой должен быть результат:

```
такси для животных
такси
такси для людей
для людей такси
для животных такси
авто такси
```

запрос может начинаться и с одной буквы.
в бд более 10 000 строк

Comment: Можно использовать сортировку по [locate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) (т.е. `ORDER BY LOCATE('такси', TEXT)), но сильно сомневаюсь, что это будет быстро (да и не знаю как будет работать с русскими буквами). Если искать всегда будете "такси", то может имеет смысл переделать структуру таблицы? Или "такси" это только пример и поиск может быть по любому слову (например, "магазин")?

Comment: это для примера. в базе более 10 000 строк

Comment: А использование сторонних инструментов возможно? Например, [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) позволяет сортировать по позиции слова (слов) в тексте. К тому же - sphinx позволяет существенно увеличить скорость поиска по большим документам. Sphinx, при этом, не единственный инструмент, который можно использовать, но про другие я не знаю ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо  *BOPOH* за подсказку.
нашел решение с  **LOCATE**

```
SELECT
    TEXT, LOCATE('авто', TEXT) as TEXT_LOCATE
FROM search_site_text
WHERE 
    (TEXT like '%авто%' OR SYNON like '%авто%')
    and (CITY = 2280 or CITY = 0)
ORDER BY TYPE asc, TEXT_LOCATE asc  
LIMIT 100
```

**LOCATE** возвращает позицию первого вхождения.

```
mysql> SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'foobarbar');
        -> 4
mysql> SELECT LOCATE('xbar', 'foobar');
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'foobarbar', 5);
        -> 7
```

Comment: Мне это решение не понравилось из-за возможного падения скорости выборки, поэтому не оформил ответ. Да и сам запрос вида `SELECT... WHERE TEXT like...` не внушает доверия в плане скорости. Может быть правда - посмотрите в сторону инструментов, предназначенных для этого? Я про sphinx (или аналогичные)

Comment: Да текущий запрос выполняется  0.1487 sec. В будущем буду думать на оптимизации. на данный момент это лучший вариант.